# Trying to remove object out of an array by it's specific element

Tags: javascript

I got an array with objects inside it, and these objects got elements inside them. How will I address one of these objects by one of the elements?

```
let randomARR = [];

let a = {"name": "John", "age": 20, "PlaceOfBirth": "Germany"};
let b = {"name": "Simon", "age": 20, "PlaceOfBirth": "France"}; 
let c = {"name": "Michael", "age": 20, "PlaceOfBirth": "USA"};

randomARR.push(a);
randomARR.push(b);
randomARR.push(c);
```

result:

```
[{"name": "John", "age": 20, "PlaceOfBirth": "Germany"}, {"name": "Simon", "age": 20, "PlaceOfBirth": "France"}, {"name": "Michael", "age": 20, "PlaceOfBirth": "USA"}]
```

Let's say I would like to remove object b (name: Simon) out of the array by addressing the object by it's element **"name"**, and not the it's position at the array.

Comment: Did you tried using filter ? Read about filter you need to use filter for such case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

It iterates over all the elements of the array and based on the boolean returns keeps/removes it from the resultant array. You can set it to the current array to overwrite it.

```
let objArr = [{"name": "John", "age": 20, "PlaceOfBirth": "Germany"}, {"name": "Simon", "age": 20, "PlaceOfBirth": "France"}, {"name": "Michael", "age": 20, "PlaceOfBirth": "USA"}]

let newObj = objArr.filter(obj => obj.name !== "Simon");

// objArr = objArr.filter(obj => obj.name !== "Simon"); to overwrite
```

Answer (score 0):

`randomARR = randomARR.filter(o => o.name != 'Simon') ;`

This is I think the way to go.